# Acceder a archivos que estan en un servidor local desde web api asp.net 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localhost, entity-framework-core

Tengo una api web desarrollada en **asp.net 6.0** y le envio peticiones desde una aplicacion web de angular y necesito que la api acceda a un servidor local que esta en la misma red que va a estar publicada la api, el servidor esta en `192.168.1.75` y mi computadora donde ejecuto la api mientras aun esta en desarrollo esta en la 80, necesito acceder a los archivos que están alojados en un directorio allí.

El problema es que el servidor necesita un usuario y una contraseña para lograr acceder a sus recursos y no consigo hacer que mi api se autentique, he intentado varias formas como usando una petición httpClient configurándole las credenciales manualmente para asegurarme que estén correctas y aun así no logro acceder, siempre me da error, archivo no encontrado, y la ruta y las credenciales sí están correctas, este sería el método que estoy probando:

```
public IHttpActionResult ObtenerArchivoDesdeServidor()
    {
        // Ruta de la carpeta compartida en el servidor
        string rutaServidor = @"\\192.168.1.75\Solicitudes\Solicitud_Cotizacion\COT19-pdf file.pdf";

        
        string usuario = "usuario";
        string contraseña = "contraseña";

        try
        {
            NetworkCredential credenciales = new NetworkCredential(usuario, contraseña);

            using (new NetworkConnection(rutaServidor, credenciales))
            {
                byte[] archivoBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(rutaServidor);
                return File(archivoBytes, "application/pdf", "COT19-pdf file.pdf");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

También estuve probando de otra forma y me daba otro error, me salia schema not supported:

```
public IActionResult nuevometodo(string fileName)
{
    
    try
    {
        string rutaBase = @"\\192.168.1.75\Solicitudes\";
        string filePath = Path.Combine(rutaBase, fileName);

        //extrae las credenciales de la base de datos y desencripta la contraseña
        var credentialsDB = _context.ParamsConfs.FirstOrDefault(cr => cr.Identify == "SVSOLICITUDES");
        var svPass = _cryptoService.DecryptPassword(credentialsDB.Pass);

        //credenciales del servidor de archivos
        string username = credentialsDB.Content;
        string password = svPass;


        //configuracion de las credenciales para el objeto httpclient
        NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        // Crear un HttpClient personalizado con las credenciales
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Credentials = networkCredential.GetCredential(new Uri(rutaBase), "Basic")
        });

        // Realiza una solicitud HEAD para verificar la existencia del archivo
        HttpResponseMessage headResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, rutaBase + fileName)).Result;

        if (headResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // El archivo existe en el servidor, procede a descargarlo como arreglo de bytes
            HttpResponseMessage getResponse = httpClient.GetAsync(rutaBase + fileName).Result;
            if (getResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = getResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                return File(fileBytes, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                // Manejar el error de descarga del archivo
                return StatusCode((int)getResponse.StatusCode, "Error al descargar el archivo: " + getResponse.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
        else if (headResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            // El archivo no existe en el servidor.
            return NotFound("El archivo no existe en el servidor.");
        }
        else
        {
            // Manejar otros errores de la solicitud HEAD
            return StatusCode((int)headResponse.StatusCode, "Error al verificar la existencia del archivo: " + headResponse.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Catch exterior, error en archivo: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Me serviría de mucho si me pueden ayudara  corregir mi código o si existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo y que sea segura.